# How can I make my iOS app backward compatible?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've built an app for iOS 8 with xCode 6. The app is already on the app store. How can I make it available for people who are still using iOS 7 or even 6?

Comment: Set the target iOS deployment version to 6.0 or 7.0, but keep the base SDK to 8.0 inside your Build Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change iOS deployment target 8.0. then people has os lower then 8.0 not able to download this new version.

to available for them ,you have to set iOS deployment target to 6.0 or 7.0.[image: img]